# Why Is it that every action I do Is the opposite action?

Tags: keyboard, test-drive-unlimited-2

Every time I play test drive unlimited 2, when I press forward on my keyboard my car goes backwards.  Also if I press Ok it thinks I have hit backspace and it will flash the *no* button which means no Is Ok and Ok Is no!  Why is it doing this, and how do I set up my keyboard mapping properly?

Comment: It seems like you're stuck on Opposite day (http://en.spongepedia.org/index.php?title=Opposite_Day_%28Episode%29) Check your system date to not be the 25th of January.

Comment: The system date Is right

Comment: Have you remapped your keys (either as a cause of the problem or to try and fix it)?

Comment: I seem to have fixed the left and right and forward and backward keys but not the numbers and letters